# Prepend IN values to table in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi is there a way to attached IN value to results table.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT t.*,
       tt.*
FROM wp_terms AS t
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('nationality')
  AND tr.object_id IN (1099,
                       1401,
                       1646,
                       1087,
                       1610,
                       1293)
ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

I would like to attach `1099, 1401, 1646, 1087, 1610, 1293` to table results that are not empty. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What does it mean to attach something "to table results that are not empty"?

Comment: The query at the top retrieves results terms that are belonging to the following ids 1099, 1401, 1646, 1087, 1610, 1293, I need those results to contain extra column with related id.

Comment: can you give some example ?

Comment: You have to create temporary table and use it.

Comment: adding `tr.object_id` in `select` might help you

Comment: for example I receive the flowing columns `term.id, term.name`, I need to attach extra column that would have related id like so `term.id, term.name, related.id = 1099`

Comment: Please add tables and insert queries and expected output.

Comment: these columns are in which table ?

Comment: @an33sh thanks that is what I was looking for. Great thank you very much.

Comment: @AndriusSolopovas you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Just add the column you want to see to the results of select command:

```
    SELECT t.*,
           tt.*,
           tr.object_id
    FROM wp_terms AS t
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
    WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('nationality')
      AND tr.object_id IN (1099,
                           1401,
                           1646,
                           1087,
                           1610,
                           1293)
    ORDER BY t.name ASC
```